# create regex for several matches

Tags: regex

I shall test a date string to see if it is one of these three:
dd-mm-yyyy OR yyyy OR dd-mm-yyyy/dd-mm-yyyy

I have combine these three, but the last one makes trouble since I cannot just match a single "/" using \Q/\E.

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}                                -> dd-mm-yyyy
[0-9]{4}                                                  -> yyyy
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\Q/\E[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4} -> dd-mm-yyyy/dd-mm-yyyy
```

Combined they will give this expression:

```
([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\Q/\E[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})
```

Question 1: How to only allow a single "/" between the dates?

Question 2: What does a ^ mean in the start of a regex and $ in the end? And should 
I have it in mine

Br. Anders

UPDATE: (based on answers and comments below) Thanks! Two right answer. I marked the last one right since there also was a much smoother way to write what I had tried to do.

Language is probably XSLT or C#. It is in the CMS Umbraco that I place a regex to validate a default texstring/input field.

It acts a bit funny. There is no difference if I add  a ^ to the start, therefore my question about that.

This string works perfekt: ^(?:\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?:/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})?)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a language, I'll suggest a working Perl version:

```
/^(?:\d{4}|\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?:\/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})?)$/
```

Pattern explained:

- start at the first character of the string
- look for 4 digits ( `\d{4}` )
- OR
- a sequence of `two digits dash two digits dash four digits`
- optionally `a slash two digits dash two digits dash four digits`
- match the end of the string to make sure there is nothing else

I quoted the literal `/` writing `\/` as it's the most cross-language way to do it: in Perl it would be enough to choose different pattern delimiter to avoid the need of escaping.

Comment: Thanks. A much shorter regex than mine. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you told us which regexp variant or programming language you are using.  I'll assume perl for the moment.

- Question 1: escape it using a backslash (`\`) : `\/`.
- Question 2: `^` means the start of the input, `$` means the end.  using both means match lines which exactly match my query, with no other stuff at the start or end.  Since you want to match *date strings*, and not *strings with a date in them*, you **should** use them in your query

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use Umbraco and guess it must validate regex using C# or XSLT. Umbraco payes no attention to the ^ and the $. Therefore my question about that since I was a bit confused. Will say it is a need-to-look-into for the Umbraco people.